# How to enable fingerprint in hp zbook g2 14?

Tags: 20.04, hp, fingerprint-reader

I do not see the fingerprint option to enable it in the settings in the user's section

[image: img_fingerprint]

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: No, the problem is that I don't see the option to activate the fingerprint in users